# Firefox URL Suggestion filtering

Tags: firefox, history

As the web browsing addict that I am I visit quite a few different websites during a day. This leaves my Firefox history filled with websites and their associated pages.

*Example of history:*

- stackoverflow.com
- stackoverflow.com/questions
- stackoverflow.com/questions/somerandomquestion
- stackoverflow.com/questions/another random question
- ux.stackexchange.com
- ux.stackexchange.com/questions

When I open a new tab and start writing 'st', firefox will return all of the above urls I visited.

Now I am wondering if it is possible, with some kind of configuration and/or Firefox addon to filter these results into a more user-friendly format.

I'm looking for a way to present url suggestions as follows:

- **stackoverflow.com**
- [+] *more results from stackoverflow.com*
- **ux.stackexchange.com**
- [-] *results from ux.stackexchange.com*
- ux.stackexchange.com/questions
- ux.stackexchange.com/questions/somerandomquestionivisit

This would make my web browsing activities much more relaxing, as I usually go the the homepage of a site and browse from there, rather than going to a very specific page on that website first.

Is this possible?

If no such add-on / configuration exists, how would I go about creating such a add-on myself? ( assuming that keeps within the scope of the question )

Comment: This is a great question, I wonder if there is a chrome extension for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the results using special characters.

> - Add ^ to search for matches in your browsing history
> - Add * to search for matches your bookmarks
> - Add + to search for matches in pages you've tagged
> - Add @ to search for pages that have web addresses (URLs) that match
>     what you've typed
> - Add # to search for pages that have titles or tag names that match
>     what you've typed
> - Add % to search for pages in currently open tabs that match what
>     you've typed

So typing `st *` would show results only from the bookmarks. 
If you've bookmarked/tagged the homepages you can get only those.